# How to Choose a Text within a Div with same class but multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  need your help please. In getting something work, I've tried pulling up information from feeds and blog, yet it's not trusted.
Here is my code...

```
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Promote Channel</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Increase Conversion on Site</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Increase Conversion on App</h4>
</div>
...
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Get Video View</h4>
</div>
```

How To select and Get the text within the clicked on h4.
I Just don't know how to start, Please I need y'all help. Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: `$('h4').click(function() {alert($(this).text())});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using javascript

```js
function getTxt(x){
    alert(x.innerHTML);  
}
```

```html
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4 onclick="getTxt(this);">Promote Channel</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4 onclick="getTxt(this);">Increase Conversion on Site</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4 onclick="getTxt(this);">Increase Conversion on App</h4>
</div>
...
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4 onclick="getTxt(this);">Get Video View</h4>
</div>
```

A simple solution using jquery

```js
$(".select_obj").click(function(){
    //to get the content  
    var txt=$(this).children("h4").text();
    alert(txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Promote Channel</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Increase Conversion on Site</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Increase Conversion on App</h4>
</div>
...
<div class="select_obj">
    <h4>Get Video View</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery you can do like this

```js
$('h4').on('click',function(event){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Promote Channel</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Increase Conversion on Site</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Increase Conversion on App</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Get Video View</h4>
</div>
```

Using native javascript

```js
var getAllH4 = document.querySelectorAll('h4');
getAllH4.forEach(function(item, index) {
  (function(item, i) { // creating closure
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(item.textContent);
    });
  }(item, index))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Promote Channel</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Increase Conversion on Site</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Increase Conversion on App</h4>
</div>
<div class="select_obj">
  <h4>Get Video View</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is My code ..... I give them id's and sending the id of the clicked element with the function the return the text that you click on it ...

```
          <h4 id="a" onclick="getText(id)">Promote Channel</h4>
        </div>
        <div  class="select_obj">
          <h4 id="b" onclick="getText(id)">Increase Conversion on Site</h4>
        </div>
        <div  class="select_obj">
          <h4 id="c" onclick="getText(id)">Increase Conversion on App</h4>
        </div>
        ...
        <div  class="select_obj">
          <h4 id="d" onclick="getText(id)">Get Video View</h4>
        </div>
```

ok using javascript .....

```
    <script>
            function getText(id)
            {
                var textReturned ="";
                textReturned = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
                alert(textReturned);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I cannot understand what is the unuseful thing in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('h4').on('click',function(){alert($(this).text()) ;});
```